# Compute a kernel matrix with a custom kernel function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

is there a way to create something like a correlation matrix with a different function:

starting from this:

```
X = array([[1, 1, 1],
          [2, 2, 2],
          [3, 3, 3]])
```

which is in the shape: (n_samples, n_features) and turn it into something like this:

```
array([[f(X[0],X[0]),f(X[0],X[1]),f(X[0],X[2])],
       [f(X[1],X[0]), f(X[1],X[1]),f(X[1],X[2])],
       [f(X[2],X[0]), f(X[2],X[1]),f(X[2],X[2])]])
```

thanks!

which is essentially all samples passed to a function with eachother

so the way i currenty solve it is with  a nested loop:

```
for i in range(samples):
    for j in range(samples):
        r = test_kernel(X[i],X[j])
        output[i,j] = r
```

but i doubt thats the most efficient way to do it, since i the matrix is symetrical, i have to do multiple calculations twice

Comment: Can you give an example of the function?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your question, you are searching for a possibility to use some custom metric to define a kernel matrix based on a vector as input. You can use `pairwise_kernels` from `sklearn.metrics.pairwise`:

## Vector as input

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_kernels

x = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
print('Input vector:\n', x)

kernel_default = pairwise_kernels(x)
print('Default metric - Squared euclidean norm as kernel function: \n', kernel_default)



def custom_kernel(x, y):
    # Here you can define your custom transform, e.g.:
    return x**3 + y**3

kernel_custom = pairwise_kernels(x, metric=custom_kernel)
print('Some custom norm, which has no meaning...:\n', kernel_custom)
```

results in

```
Input vector:
 [[1]
 [2]
 [3]]
Default metric - Squared euclidean norm as kernel function: 
 [[1. 2. 3.]
 [2. 4. 6.]
 [3. 6. 9.]]
Some custom norm, which has no meaning...:
 [[ 2.  9. 28.]
 [ 9. 16. 35.]
 [28. 35. 54.]]
```

## Multi-dimensional input

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_kernels

x = np.array([[1, 1],[2, 2],[3, 3]])
print('Input vector:\n', x)

def custom_kernel(x, y):
    # Here you can define your custom transform, e.g.:
    return np.sum(x)**3 + np.sum(y)**3

kernel_custom = pairwise_kernels(x, metric=custom_kernel)
print('Some custom norm, which has no meaning...:\n', kernel_custom)
```

results in

```
Input vector:
 [[1 1]
 [2 2]
 [3 3]]
Some custom norm, which has no meaning...:
 [[ 16.  72. 224.]
 [ 72. 128. 280.]
 [224. 280. 432.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

array([[f(X[i],X[j]) for i in range (len(X))] for j in range (len(X))])?